# Keil Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions - Using STM32F103RE

Tags: keil, space

I have written a sample EMWIN Project in KEIL using its package manager, shown below.

[image: KEIL Package Pic]

When I use the Build Project icon I get the following error:

```
.\Objects\test.axf: Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching rtx_conf_cm.o(.bss).
```

As shown here:

[image: error pic]

My keil code can be found here:

[The csource Code](https://www.4shared.com/s/fwQEsG6kbda)

> NEW Update:
>
> So my IROM1 && IRAM1 setting shown below:
>
> [image: IROM1 && IRAM1]
>
> So have I could change those constance for solving this error?

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your selected MCU does not have enough space in flash to store the program.

Indicated by this forum post: [ST Forum Link](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkYZnSAN/event-recorder-on-stm32f030k6t6-error)

Comment: maybe but I have only added emwin package to Keil without any image array which uses extra memory.

Comment: I don't know much about emwin but I would assume it must still use some memory even without the image array. Are you able to compile and load/run the project without emwin?

Comment: Looking at this resource usage chart it is quite memory intensive, the MCU yoube picked looks like it only has 512kB flash - https://www.segger.com/products/user-interface/emwin/technology/emwin-resource-usage/

Comment: I think total emwin pack which I used is less than 100kb, so I haven't added any more file like a picture or ... so why this error happened, you could check the source file via the question.

Comment: in the keil site said:` "In the licensed (non-evaluation) version of MDK-ARM, the Memory Areas parameters automatically configure the scatter file for the RealView Linker/Locator. " `   via this link:[link](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/mcbstm32f200/mcbstm32f200_wp_cap_params.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have an installation of Keil to check. Double check the configuration in the package manager that nothing else has been selected. You might also want to try posting on the keil forum: http://www.keil.com/forum/ or you could even try the mbed forum as that STM device is mbed compatible so someone might have had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There are errors when linking the .data sections. You're probably asking for too much SRAM.
Which makes sense seeing that you're trying to fit a graphics library.

The STM32F103 alone won't fit a color frame buffer. You need this memory on the display, or external.