# How to write the scatter file for Keil uVision to force linker to allocate variables in SRAM?

Tags: stm32, c, ram, keil, linker

### Development environment

I'm working with STM32F427 and I use Keil uVision V5.29 to develop my application. The version of the ArmCLang Compiler, of the Assembler and the linker is 6.131.1.

### Scatter file and `__attribute__` directive

I need to allocate some variables in the SRAM into the address interval:
`[0x20000000, 0x20030000]`
The variables are at least the following:

```
ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT];
ETH_DMADescTypeDef  DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TX_DESC_CNT];
```

I have tried with the `__attribute__` directive as following:

```
ETH_DMADescTypeDef DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT] __attribute__((section(".ram1")));
ETH_DMADescTypeDef DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TX_DESC_CNT] __attribute__((section(".ram1")));
```

I have defined the following scatter file:

```
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00030000  {  ; RW data
   *(.ram1)
  }
  RW_IRAM2 0x10000000 0x00010000  {  ; CCM
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

### Compilation error

If I compile the project with the previous scatter file (with or without the `__attribute__` directive) the compilation output shoes many of the following error:

```
...: Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching app_azure_rtos.o(.bss.variable_name).
```

### My question

Where is it the error in the previous scatter file?

---

**EDIT**
I have found [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420616/keil-error-l6406e-no-space-in-execution-regions-using-stm32f103re) which suggests that there is not enough resource for the program.

But if I use the following scatter file (where it is **completely excluded the CCM memory** and this means that 56 Kbytes of RAM are not used):

```
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00030000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

the compilation ends successfully. This means that the problem is in the scatter file not in the memory resources.

Comment: _"I need to allocate some variables in the SRAM into the address interval:
[0x20000000, 0x20030000]"_ - Why?

Comment: @Bruce In [this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/654733/why-does-ethernet-stop-working-if-the-value-of-ethernet-dma-control-registers-re) I have explained in details why I have to allocate that variables in SRAM and not in CCM (**DMA can't access to CCM**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I have found the necessary and missed option for my scatter file.
To compile the project it is sufficient adding the following option to the `RW_IRAM1` region:

```
.ANY (+RW +ZI)
```

where `RW` means *Read/Write* and `ZI` means *Zero Initialized*.

### Correct scatter file

So the correct scatter file for my needs is:

```
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00030000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
   *(.ram1)
  }
  RW_IRAM2 0x10000000 0x00010000  {  ; CCM
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

### The `__attribute__` directive

With the previous scatter file I have used the `__attribute__` directive as following:

```
ETH_DMADescTypeDef DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RX_DESC_CNT] __attribute__((section(".ram1")));
ETH_DMADescTypeDef DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TX_DESC_CNT] __attribute__((section(".ram1")));
```

In this way the 2 arrays are **always** allocated in the addresses interval:
`[0x20000000, 0x20030000]`

---

My real need is to avoid that the Ethernet DMA controller have to access to CCM memory, because it can't. This goal is reached if the previous arrays (`DMARxDscrTab` and `DMATxDscrTab`) are not allocated in CCM.

To get more details about this topic see [this other post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/654733/why-does-ethernet-stop-working-if-the-value-of-ethernet-dma-control-registers-re).